# Selenium 4.15.2 asks for location of driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
File "C:\Users\ivanc\anaconda3\envs\alt-intel-sa\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

This is my code

```
def scrape_urls(
    self, starting_url="https://www.linkedin.com/company/jsafrasarasin/jobs/"
):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    ## scraping code ##
```

This code was working last week but for some reason it did not and return me the error message above. Based on the latest version of the selenium documentation, it says that I do not have to specify the path of the webdriver or am I missing something? Is this a bug with the new release of selenium? Currently, I am using conda forge 4.15.2.

### edit

downgrading the version of selenium to 4.13.0 fixed this issue for me